# How can I register a COM-Object with Windows Installer XML

Tags: com, wix

I have got the following Problem: In my WiX Setup I need to register a COM Object. I have got a ".tlb" File and a ".dll" File (in my example: XYCommon.dll and a XYCommon.tlb)
Now I want to make the Setup to Register the TLB.
How Can I do this in Windows Installer XML ?

My first try was to work with a CustomAction and Open "Regasm.exe" and Register it - but I dont know how I can bring the Regasm.exe to Register the XYCommon.tlb

Any Help ? Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Use the WiX harvester utility called [Heat](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm). It will generate the WiX source that contains the necessary registry entries to correctly register (and unregister) your COM objects.

Will your COM objects (XYCommon.dll and XYCommon.tlb) change often?

**If no:** then just run Heat on those two files (read up on the command-line parameters and experiment with them to get the desired output), clean them up if necessary, and add them to your project.

**If yes:**

If you want to try to run Heat as a Visual Studio prebuild event, this SO answer should give you some guidance: [Add a folder to installer in wix not files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121092/add-a-folder-to-installer-in-wix-not-files/11121289#11121289)

Sometimes when you use Heat you still need to tweak then generated .wxs files a little. Therefore you may want to write some wrapper utility that calls heat on a list of files or a directory, then cleans up the output how you would like. Then you can add the utility to your build process.

**Example of using heat on an individual file:**

> heat.exe file myFile.dll -gg -g1 -suid -svb6 -out myFile.wxs

**Example of using heat on an entire directory:**

> heat.exe dir myDirectory -gg -g1 -suid -svb6 -out myDirectory.wxs

Breakdown of some of the parameters I used:

- heat.exe: you'll have to specify the full path to the executable if it's not in your path
- file myFile.dll: specify that you want to run heat on the single file, myFile.dll
- dir myDirectory: specify that you want to run heat on the directory, myDirectory
- gg: generate guids for the components
- g1: generate guids without the curly braces
- suid: suppress creating uniquely generated ids for files and components, instead use the file names as the ids
- svb6: suppress harvesting COM information for the VB6 runtime. Note: If you want to register COM objects that use the VB6 runtime, you need to use this flag so that you do not overwrite your VB6 runtime registry entries

Comment: Ah I forgot something neccessary: I am building my Project in Visual Studio 2012. And the whole Project is in Visual Studio. Can you help me ?

Comment: Hello Bryan, thank you for your quick answer! I will try the Heat. But, can you help me or show me a link which parameters I need to write to Register the File ?

Comment: @SebastianSchwarz, I added some examples.

Comment: Are these the Parameters i Use in the Visual Studio - Propertys - Pre Build Events ?

Comment: You will need -gg and if your COM objects are VB6 components then you need -svb6 as well. The rest you probably don't need. There may be some other adjustments you have to make if running as a prebuild event and trying to get everything to compile correctly, but you can give it a try and post any issues you have.